# Number of possible permutations and combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have $3$ types of cards - Red ($R$), Green ($G$) and Blue ($B$). And they have to be placed on trays where there are multiple slots where each slot can hold exactly one card. The player/user is given a choice of choosing from the following options:

1. a 3-slot tray, where any card type $(R,G,B)$ can occupy any slot. for example, $RRG, RGB, BRR$ etc.
2. a 4-slot tray, where the first slot can be occupied by only one of the card types $G$ or $B$ and the remaining $3$ can be occupied by any of the the card types. for example, $BRRG, GRGB, BBRR$ etc.
3. a 5-slot tray, where the first slot can be occupied by only one of the card types $G$ or $B$ and the remaining $4$ can be occupied by any of the the card types. for example, $GRRBG, GRRGB, BGRRG$ etc.

How many permutations and combinations are possible for each of the above scenarios, given that the player will have exactly the same number of cards in hand as there are slots in the trays he chose? Is $3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 27$ and $2\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 54$ and $2\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 162$ the right answer? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Added my deductions.

Comment: Your answers are correct.